# Review summary padding appears to be missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, design

It seems that there recently was an update on the layout of the review queues. When I went back to an earlier reviewed suggested edit, I noticed that the review summary was looking a bit odd.

It appears that the left padding is missing:

[image]

I checked this on both Chrome and IE, and they appear the same on both browsers. I also checked for other queues, but also there the text is hitting the left border.

Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18170783) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11546286).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be fixed now, sorry about that.

I migrated that review bar container to flexbox, the implementation of which required moving the padding to margins on the children, and I missed this case.